# With Google App Engine, why is there a huge difference in memory reporting between the profiler and the App Engine dashboard?

Tags: google-app-engine, memory-management, google-cloud-platform, profiler

In my App Engine dashboard, I noticed my app was using huge amounts of memory for hardly any usage (2 users, testing it out). This service was hosted in a flex environment with node.js so I installed Google's Profiler to try and understand what is going on. Google's Profiler reported very normal memory usage, however, (~4.3MiB from Google's Profiler vs ~2.5GiB from the App Engine dashboard), which does not explain the App Engine's dashboard's report of GiB's of memory usage. What could be going on in this case?

[image: Google Profiler]

[image: App Engine Dashboard]

*Edit*

I SSH'd into one of the instances and ran `top`. Here are the results. What I'm confused about, is that I thought if you don't specify manual scaling, App Engine will use an F1 type server, which has a maximum of 256 MB of memory. Here it is saying I have 288.2 MiB of memory available (and the server has 988.3 MiB total), so I wonder if that's normal.

[image: running top]

Comment: Hard to troubleshoot such issue here as they require more visibility into instance. I would recommend to open a ticket with GCP support if you have support package to find explanation to this. The only thing I can think of is that Dashboard shows instance memory usage rather than app's and [Linux ate your RAM](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/).

Comment: Hmm... Well, it seems most likely that it's the "Linux ate your RAM" scenario, but I'm a little confused on how App Engine handles everything. I am using the default scaling, so I assume the instance is an F1 instance. However, `top` shows about 988 MiB of RAM total. Is this just how AE works? I do have over 256 MiB available, however. What I'm worried about is it's starting 2 instances with there being hardly any usage.

Comment: As you are able to ssh into the instance it looks like you use flexible environment and its instances has [different resources](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#resource-settings). As for why it spawns additional instances try tweaking [automatic scaling parameters](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#automatic_scaling).